# regex to ignore duplicate matches

Tags: html, regex

I'm using an application to search this website that I don't have control of right this moment and was wondering if there is a way to ignore duplicate matches using only regex.

Right now I wrote this to get matches for the image source in the pages source code

uses this to retrieve srcs

```
<span> <img id="imgProduct.*? src="/(.*?)" alt="
```

from this

```
<span> <img id="imgProduct_1" class="SmPrdImg selected"     
onclick="(some javascript);" src="the_src_I_want1.jpg" alt="woohee"> </span>
<span> <img id="imgProduct_2" class="SmPrdImg selected"     
onclick="(some javascript);" src="the_src_I_want2.jpg" alt="woohee"> </span>
<span> <img id="imgProduct_3" class="SmPrdImg selected"     
onclick="(some javascript);" src="the_src_I_want3.jpg" alt="woohee"> </span>
```

the only problem is that the exact same code listed above is duplicated way lower in the source. Is there a way to ignore or delete the duplicates using only regex?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: @Truth: He's not actually parsing HTML, though, he just wants the `src` attribute. Regex can handle that much, since there's no need to do bracket balancing.

Comment: Parsing HTML using regex has been covered extensively on SO.  The consensus is that it should not be done.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @AbeMiessler: See above re:Truth's comment. This is not the same as that. I love that page and agree with every word, but this question is not the same.

Comment: Use XPath instead, it should be very easy to extract the set of nodes you want without explicitly parsing the document. I'd have to know a bit more about the structure and the exact nodes you want to keep to provide a query.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: I disagree. If his source changes (more spaces, change of quotes anything like that) The regex breaks, while a parser does not. So no, your comment has little merit.

Comment: @Truth: You are correct that regex is a bad idea. You are incorrect in including that link, because that link does not address *why* regex is a bad idea *in this case.* Moreover, a more robust pattern that doesn't break with minor source changes is quite possible; see my answer.

Comment: Well lets give both options (I'm with DragoonWraith - whilst DOM is a more elegant approach, if you know exactly what you need to match then why bother using DOM!) - use //img[@src] to get all images with a source attribute, I don't however think you'll be able to ensure they are unique so you'll need a dedupe added.

Comment: @truth the only bad thing is I don't actually have access to the site till the handover to our company is complete so the source won't change until we change it ^_^. Using this search app that uses regex is the only option we have right now unless you know something I don't (which you probably do)

Comment: @williamvicary your way would work great if I only had access to the website in question. The webmaster on their side is being a pain with getting it handed over. I wish I could work with the DOM but I can't. I do know exactly where to find it! just need to get rid of these duplicate matches to make the gather go more smoothly X-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern's not very good; it's way too specific to your exact source code as it currently exists. As @Truth commented, if that changes, you'll break your pattern. I'd recommend something more like this:

```
<img[^>]*src=['"]([^'"]*)['"]
```

That will match the contents of any `src` attribute inside any `<img>` tag, no matter how much your source code changes.

To prevent duplicates with regex, you'll need lookahead, and this is likely to be **very** slow. I do **not recommend** using regex for this. This is just to show that you could, if you had to. The pattern you would need is something like this (I tested this using Notepad++'s regex search, which is based on PCRE and more robust than JavaScript's, but I'm reasonably sure that JavaScript's regex parser can handle this).

```
<img[^>]*src=['"]([^'"]*)['"](?!(?:.|\s)*<img[^>]*src=['"]\1['"])
```

You'll then get a match for the last instance of every `src`.

## The Breakdown

For illustration, here's how the pattern works:

```
<img[^>]*src=['"]([^'"]*)['"]
```

This makes sure that we are inside a `<img>` tag when `src` comes up, and then makes sure we match only what is inside the quotes (which can be either single or double quotes; since neither is a legal character in a filename *anyway* we don't have to worry about mixing quote types or escaped quotes).

```
(?!
    (?:
        .
    |
        \s
    )*
    <img[^>]*src=['"]\1['"]
)
```

The `(?!` starts a negative lookahead: we are requiring that the following pattern cannot be matched after this point.

Then `(?:.|\s)*` matches any character or any whitespace. This is because JavaScript's `.` will not match a newline, while `\s` will. Mostly, I was lazy and didn't want to write out a pattern for any possible line ending, so I just used `\s`. The `*`, of course, means we can have any number of these. That means that the following (still part of the negative lookahead) cannot be found *anywhere* in the rest of the file. The `(?:` instead of `(` means that this parenthetical isn't going to be remembered for backreferences.

That bit is `<img[^>]*src=['"]\1['"]`. This is very similar to the initial pattern, but instead of capturing the `src` with `([^'"]*)`, we're referencing the previously-captured `src` with `\1`.

Thus the pattern is saying "match any `src` in an `img` that does not have any `img` with the same `src` anywhere in the rest of the file," which means you only get the last instance of each `src` and no duplicates.

If you want to remove *all* instances of any `img` whose `src` appears more than once, I think you're out of luck, by the way. JavaScript does not support lookbehind, and the overwhelming majority of regex engines that do wouldn't allow such a complicated lookbehind *anyway*.

Comment: WOW this is an amazing answer!! If I could up-vote your answer I would but sadly I'm still a noob. Also, thank you very much for explaining it the way you did since I'm extremely newb with using regex. And sadly I will have to use a look ahead since we don't have access to the site yet :( (handover issues) I have to use regex.

Comment: also I forgot to ask this, my bad, but from what I understand of this code, it will only give up a match if there is a duplicate, or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum: No, it matches every case where the same `src` is not found anywhere later in the document, i.e. the last one. If there's only one, then that one is the last one.

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum: Also, you can upvote; just click the up-arrow. If this worked for you, you can also click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: oh yeah thanks @DragoonWraith ! I can't upvote yet because I only have a reputation of 6 and you have to have at least 15... you could help by up voting my question :)

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum: Yeah, sure, why not. The only reason I hadn't to begin with is because I didn't think regex was the right approach to the problem, but you've explained that you don't have a choice, so whatever.

Comment: THANK YOU! YEAH I CAN UPVOTE NOW! *giggles*

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't work too hard to make them unique, just do that in the PHP following the preg match with array_unique:

```
$pattern = '~<span> <img id="imgProduct.*? src="/(.*?)" alt="~is';
$match   = preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);

if ($match)
{
     $matches = array_unique($matches[1]);
}
```

If you are using JavaScript, then you'd need to use another function instead of array_unique, check PHPJS:
http://phpjs.org/functions/array_unique:346

Comment: This is a massively better approach than a pure-regex solution. I do recommend a more robust pattern for the initial matching, such as `<img[^>]*src=['"]([^'"]*)['"]`. Also, there's no indication that he's actually using PHP here; I think JavaScript is what's going on. Still, this is the *idea* he wants.

Comment: Totally agree, the pattern needed some love but if he's matching data that is strict then there isn't much need to make it better, if it matches then it matches - but your right, its not a pattern that'll work consistently across multiple websites.

Comment: I think I may have ninja-edited you: there's also a concern that I don't see any indication that he's using PHP. Does JavaScript have a function similar to `array_unique` here?

Comment: @DragoonWraith your right about it being very specific. I only need it to run on one website which is why I made it so specific. thanks again for your input! I'm going to try out your regex code right now –

Comment: thank you all for you input. The only problem is I don't have access to the website at this moment because of handover issues, but we need to gather info from it ASAP so were using a browser based app to search and gather that info that uses regex to do so. Should have been more specific. @williamvicary your idea is great but I can't use php only regex searches